# viewing/connecting to devices in another subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking

Have a bit of a unique situation which I am hoping to get some help on. At home I have my main PC connected directly to the modem supplied by my ISP (reason being I have 1.5G connection and a 10G LAN port on my modem, vs my router has only 1G port for WAN and LAN). My modem subnet is 192.168.2.x (and my modem is the DHCP server for this subnet). My router (an asus AC86U if that matters, in default router mode plugged into the modem, hence the router would also have a 192.168.2.yy as the WAN IP but at the same time is the DHCP server for 192.168.50.x subnet), has a lot of my custom config including static LAN IP, IPv6, VPN for Netflix, etc etc - things that could not be supported on my modem firmware. Therefore I am connecting pretty much all my other home devices to the LAN of my router (which is 192.168.50.x), and my main wireless network is set up on my Asus router as well. On my main PC I can ping 192.168.50.1 (which is the IP of my Asus router) however pinging any other devices in that 50.x subnet would give me a "destination host unreachable" error.

I am just wondering if there is a way I can set things up so that the devices with the 192.168.50.x IP would be visible to my main PC which is on 192.168.2.x subnet? I've Googled around a little and it seems one of the suggestions is to set the Asus router in repeater mode - however my understanding is that might cause all my config (static IP/VPN config) within the 192.168.50.x to be lost which is something I am trying to avoid. At the moment I have a "cheap" way to deal with it by connecting the wired connection on my main PC to the ISP modem and connect the Wifi to router Wifi network and when I need to connect to the other devices within the router network I manually disable wired connection to force the connection switching to Wifi, obviously that's not something ideal. My main goal is I could both keep and be able to use all my router configuration (static IP/VPN and all that) but at the same time allow my main PC to connect directly to the modem so that I am not bottlenecked with the 1Gbit WAN port speed of the router (and of course try not to spend money to buy another ASUS router with 1.5G WAN port - which is not cheap). I do, however, have a few RapaberryPi lying around that's basically doing nothing - so if that's something that would help me to get to the solution to this problem I'd love to get them to do some work as well.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Asus router, which owns the `192.168.50.0/24` subnet, probably has a firewall enabled that prevents traffic from the WAN port from reaching to anything on the LAN ports, unless the connection was started from within the `192.168.50.0/24` subnet (I'm assuming that `192.168.50.1` is the IP address of the Asus router and it's visible on the WAN port of the Asus router; hence your ability to at least ping that IP address from your main PC).

You should be able to add your main PC's `192.168.2.X` IP address to the Asus router's firewall, creating a rule that grants it full access to reach into hosts behind it in the `192.168.50.0/24` subnet. You'd want the main PC's `192.168.2.X` IP address to be static too so that this firewall rule doesn't become stale.

Some routers also have a "DMZ" zone which goes in the "other direction," if you will. You can permit internal hosts on the `192.168.50.0/24` subnet to be fully opened and accessible. Traffic destined to those hosts from the WAN port will not be blocked by the firewall. However, from what I've seen, some routers only permit a single host to be in the DMZ, which doesn't do what you want (access to all hosts in the `192.168.50.0/24` subnet).

Which method you use depends on the capabilities of the Asus router, but the principle is the same: permit traffic originating from outside the subnet to penetrate the subnet. I'd prefer the firewall approach over the DMZ approach, as it requires only one update (a firewall rule) rather than adding multiple hosts to a DMZ.

---

Depending on your main PC's hardware, there is another option. If you have a spare NIC on the main PC, then you could wire that spare NIC directly into the Asus router. At this point, your main PC would be "multi-homed" and, assuming your operating system appropriately sets up the routing table, would push traffic destined to the `192.168.50.0/24` subnet over the spare NIC.

Though really, that's basically what you were already doing:

> At the moment I have a "cheap" way to deal with it by connecting the wired connection on my main PC to the ISP modem and connect the Wifi to router Wifi network and when I need to connect to the other devices within the router network I manually disable wired connection to force the connection switching to Wifi, obviously that's not something ideal

And it sounds like perhaps the operating system wasn't permitting you to both have an IP on the modem's `192.158.2.0/24` subnet *and* the Asus router's `192.168.50.0/24` subnet. Or else it was not routing traffic destined to the `192.168.50.0/24` subnet appropriately. In an ideal world, you'd be able to route all traffic **except** traffic to/from `192.168.50.0/24` through the modem, and push `192.168.50.0/24` traffic over the WiFi NIC.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great details in the answer - let me look into the firewall config of my Asus router.